# One word for Psychic phenomenon?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say "My passion is psychic" but that doesn't make sense. Psychiness doesn't sound right either and I don't want to say Psychic phenomena or activity either, I want to say one word.

Comment: Can you be more specific - telepathy (mind reading, remote viewing, etc), telekinesis (moving things with the mind), ghosts and spirit phenomena, predicting the future, mysticism, unexplained phenomena, cryptozoology (unknown animals), witchcraft, etc. And whether you're a believer or a skeptic debunker. There are some general terms used such as Psi, Forteanism, Magick, spiritism, mediumism, but they all have different shades of meaning and areas of interest (and often some kind of theoretical underpinning or specific theory about what the phenomena are).

Comment: What's wrong with the two word phrase? Do you absolutely -have- to have a single word?

Answer (score 2):

> My passion is parapsychology.

**parapsychology** (n.)

> A field of study concerned with the investigation of evidence for
> paranormal psychological phenomena (such as telepathy, clairvoyance,
> and psychokinesis) [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parapsychology)

> Parapsychology is the study of strange mental abilities that cannot be
> explained by accepted scientific theories. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/parapsychology)

---

> The common notion of **parapsychology** as the study of the paranormal
> is not embraced in this book. Rather, **parapsychology** here is
> defined as the study of experiences having the appearance of being in
> principle outside the realm of human capabilities as conceived by
> conventional scientists. [H. Irwin and C. Watt; *An Introduction to
> Parapsychology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Parapsychology_5th_ed/E3EzxyOufbgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=parapsychology%20definition&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

Answer (score 0):

*Psychic* is an adjective here, but you need a noun. If you must have one word, try *divination*:

> *My passion is divination.*

> **divination**, *n.*
> **1.** The action or practice of divining; the foretelling of future events or discovery of what is hidden or obscure by supernatural or
> magical means; soothsaying, augury, prophecy.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford
> English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

If you can accept an article, you could try:

> *My passion is the paranormal.*

> **paranormal**, *adj.* and *n.*
> **A**. *adj.*
>  Designating supposed psychical events and phenomena such as clairvoyance or telekinesis whose operation is outside the
> scope of the known laws of nature or of normal.
> **B**. *n.*
> With *the*.
> Paranormal phenomena collectively, esp. as a field of research or
> study.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>